# Continuously adding y to an integer every x seconds until the program executes

Tags: python, time

Can a program add y to an integer every x seconds until the program is exited and have the user do something else in the process?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, though the details involving how to do so depend on your program.

Comment: for example i want to add 1 every second and have the user write something which took x seconds. then i want my program to print how long it took.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your comment,

```
from time import time

start = time()
user_input = input()
end = time()

print(end - start)
```